# django sentry doesn't work with oracle backend

Tags: django, oracle, django-south, sentry

I've just installed django sentry and configured it to use oracle backend. Unfortunately sentry web interface doesn't work properly and on the console I can see this type of errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven-2.0.6-py2.7.egg/raven/utils/serializer/manager.py", line 69, in transform
    return self.transform(repr(value))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/context.py", line 29, in __repr__
    return repr(self.dicts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/template/context.py", line 29, in __repr__
  return repr(self.dicts)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 72, in __repr__
  data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 87, in __len__
  self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in iterator
  for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763, in results_iter
  for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
  cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 675, in execute
  return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
DatabaseError: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I supposed the problem is caused by south which is sentry dependency and has only alpha support for the oracle backend. Does anyone have experience with that?

Also, how can I see actual SQL statements produced by ORM? How to configure sentry to see that? That would be very helpful.

Comment: [debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) will help you see the generated sql. If you install it with default settings, you'll get a toolbar along the right side of each page with a tab that shows all sql queries that happened during that page load. It also offers a `manage.py debugsqlshell` command which is a normal django shell but also prints out all sql used.